# Caching query results, to do or not to do, overkill or performance energizer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mean-stack, nosql

Good evening,

my project uses the MEAN Stack and has a few collections and a single database from which the data is retrieved.

Thinking about how the user would interface itself with the webapp I am going to build, I figured that my idea of the application is quite a bit of a waste.

Now, the application is hosted on a private server on the LAN, making it very fast on requests and it's running an express server.

The application is made around employee management, services and places where the services can take place. Just describing, so to have an idea.

The "ring to rule them all" is pretty much the first collection, services, which starts the core of the application. There's a page that let's you add rows, one for each service that you intend to do and within that row you choose an employee to "run the service", based on characteristics that this employee has, meaning that if the service is about teaching Piano, the employee must know how to play Piano. The same logic works for the rest of the "columns" that will build up my row into a full service recognized by the app as such.

Now, what I said above is pretty much information retrieval from a database and logic to make the application model the information retrieved and build something with it.

My question or rather my doubt comes from how I imagined the querying to work for each field that is part of the service row. Right now I'm thinking about querying the database (mongodb) each time I have to pick a value for a field, but if you consider that I might want to add a 100 rows, each of which would have 10 fields, that would make up for a lot of requests to the database. Now, that doesn't seem elegant, nor intelligent to me, but I can't come up with a better solution or idea.

Any suggestions or rule of thumbs for a MEAN newb?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Answer to a comment question which was needed.

> No, the database is pretty static (unless the user willingly inserts a new value, say a new employee that can do a service). That wouldn't happen very often. Considering the query that would return all the employees for a given service, those employees would (ideally) be inside an associative array, with the possibility to be "pop'd" from it if chosen for a service, making them unavailable for further services (because one person can't do two services at the same time). Hope I was clear, I'm surely not the best person at explaining oneself.

Comment: For clarification, are you considering updating the database every time a field in an HTML form is updated or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: No, the database is pretty static (unless the user willingly inserts a new value, say a new employee that can do a service). That wouldn't happen very often.

Considering the query that would return all the employees for a given service, those employees would (ideally) be inside an associative array, with the possibility to be "pop'd" from it if chosen for a service, making them unavailable for further services (because one person can't do two services at the same time). Hope I was clear, I'm surely not the best person at explaining oneself.

Comment: From what I understand it would like each person in the database should have a list of services they can do. Each service should have a list of employees available to do the service.

Comment: @StevenBayer yes, that is the general idea.

Comment: That seems standard for a nosql database like mongo or is there another question in there?

Comment: I'm confused as to how I would practically do it. Would I store the values returned from the query and after that work on that for the whole life of the application (until the server is restarted)?

Would that make the query to be run once for each time the server is restarted?

Comment: It would query the database on who is available when a user looks at that page and another query if the user assigns an employee to do a service.

Answer (score 0):

It would query the database on who is available when a user looks at that page and another query if the user assigns an employee to do a service.

In general 1 query on page load and another when data is submitted is standard.

You would only want to use an in memory cache for

1. frequent queries but most databases will do this automatically.
2. values that change frequently like:

   1. How many users are connected
   2. Last query sent
   3. Something that happens on almost every query (>95%)